# Archive automatically in Instapaper

Tags: instapaper

When I read articles in Instapaper I usually click the link directly or just get the text link.

Is there any way, when I open the link in browser windows, for Instapaper automatically to archive the links?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible, but I'm guessing you might like http://brettterpstra.com/instapaperbeyond/

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature to automatically archive links when they are opened.

However, I went ahead and requested the feature for you.

This was the response;

> Thanks for writing in. I've filed a feature request for auto-archive
>   options and we'll keep that in mind for future developments. Thanks
>   again for the request and for using Instapaper!
>
> Rodion, Instapaper Support